# Join two relations (candidates) and display difference between votes?

Tags: apache-pig

I first split the relation into those who won and those who lost.

I have trouble with joining the all the candidates back together and making tuples with the last names of both candidates (elected and defeated) and the difference between their vote totals (only tuples where the difference is less than 10).

```
 --load the data 
raw = LOAD '.../data2.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS  (
        date, type:chararray, parl:int, prov:chararray, riding:chararray, 
        lastname:chararray, firstname:chararray, gender:chararray,
        occupation:chararray, party:chararray, votes:int,
        percent:double, elected:int);

fltrd = FILTER raw by votes > 100 ;
spltrd = SPLIT fltrd INTO won IF elected > 0, lost IF elected == 0;
jnd = JOIN won BY lastname AS lastname_won, lost BY lastname AS lastname_lost;
```

For displaying the difference btw the votes this is the idea I had but it's not working:

```
jnd = JOIN won BY lastname AS lastname_won, vote AS vote_won, lost BY lastname AS lastname_lost, vote AS vote_lost;

gen = foreach jnd generate lastname_won, lastname_lost,(vote_won - vote_lost) as diffVotes;
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is is that is not working?

At first glance, your Join will probably not work because of the AS you are using. You cannot rename the columns in the join, you'll need a foreach for this. Use :: to distinguish between the fields from the two relations:

```
jnd2 = FOREACH jnd GENERATE won::lastname AS lastname_won, won::vote AS vote_won etc.
```

If you join on multiple columns change the syntax as follows:

```
jnd = JOIN won BY (lastname, vote), lost BY (lastname, vote);
```